# Second opinion about elimination of possible redundant database column

Tags: database-design

We currently have a `Widgets` database table were we track the widgets the company produces. When a widget is produced the widget information is added to this table. This `Widgets` table contains a `Status` column used to keep track of whether a widget is in inventory or if it has been shipped. So basically, if the widget is in inventory the value of this column is Inventory and if the widget has been shipped the value of the column is Shipped.

We also have a `Shipped Widgets` table were we track the widgets being shipped. When a widget gets shipped we add its id (and some other information) to this table.

What I would like to do now is to remove the `Status` column from the `Widgets` table because I consider the column to be redundant since we could just as easily use the `Shipped Widgets` table to determine if a widget is in inventory or if it has been shipped. In other words, if the widget is not in the `Shipped Widgets` table it means that is in Inventory and if the widget is in the `Shipped Widgets` table it means it has been Shipped.

One obvious issue with this change is that right now, if all I want is to find out what Widgets are in inventory all I need to do is query the `Widgets` table for a `Status` value equals to Inventory and I am done. However, after I remove the Status column I will need to use a more elaborated query that retrieves the Widgets that are on the `Widgets` table that don’t exist on the `Shipped Widgets` table. This may slow things down a little but I hope the benefits outweigh the cons.

This all looks pretty obvious and maybe like a good idea but before I proceed and make the changes I was wondering if anyone sees something wrong with this approach. I just don’t want to make the change a latter regret it because I failed to notice a critical drawback.

Thank you.

Comment: You can test efficiency of the query you fear may be a problem, even now, without changing the design (or even beter in a test batabase with many more data). If it behaves well enough, you can then change your design.

Comment: @ypercube: I was already planning on running a test to verify that the changes won't slow the system down dramatically. What I am hoping for is for feedback reassuring me that the changes I want to do are sound... don't want to regret the changes later. Thank you very much.